# Transfer integer to string

Tags: fortran

I am transfering an integer to a string using the following method

```
Character (len=10) :: s
Integer :: i
i = 7
Write (s, *, iostat=ios) i
```

However this leaves the contents of `s` empty. When I introduce an explicit format, `s` is populated as intended.

```
Character (len=10) :: s
Integer :: i
i = 7
Write (s, "(i3)", iostat=ios) i
```

It looks like the problem is related to the length of the string `s` because
when I use a longer length, I do get the correct number.

```
Character (len=25) :: s
```

Comment: Do you check the value of `ios` in the first case?  What do you get for `LEN_TRIM(s)` in the second?  [I guess it's greater than 10.]

Comment: ios is -2 when using fmt=*, len_trim(s) is 10

Comment: So just use `iomsg` too and read why it fails.

Comment: ios is 0 when using fmt="(i3)", and len_trim(s) is 3

Comment: ios = -2 means End of record

Comment: I'm sure that there is no explicit declaration of `ios` isn't a problem (either implicit or you've declared elsewhere would be fine), but for completeness you may want to add that in.  [I didn't when I was tidying, just in case...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first lesson to take from this is: if you use the `iostat=` specifier, check the result.  However, the behaviour of your code is seemingly not guaranteed.  I'll base this part of the answer on intepreting how your compiler is taking things.

In addition to the `iostat=` specifier, in general you can use, as Vladimir F mentions in a comment, the `iomsg=` specifier to get a friendly message.  [As IanH notes, the nominated variable is updated, and in particular may otherwise remain undefined, only in situations where the variable for the `iostat=` specifier is (or would be) set to non-zero.]

```
character (len=10) s
character (len=58) mesg
integer ios

write(s,*, iostat=ios, iomsg=mesg) 7
if (ios/=0) print*, ios, TRIM(mesg)
```

You want to check this, because you are using list-directed output.  Here, the compiler is free to choose "reasonable" values for the integer edit format.  It's more than likely that, for default integer kind, the field would be longer than 9 (don't forget the leading blank).  Thus, it doesn't "fit" into the length-10 character record: "End of record" would be reasonable for `mesg` in this case.

With the explicit format `I3` it fits with much to spare.

Why you see `LEN_TRIM(s)` as 10, is that `s` actually likely becomes junk.

Now, coming to the final part.  It appears that your code with list-directed output is not valid.  Fortran 2008 (and I presume many others) explicitly states:

> On output, the output list and format specification shall not specify more characters for a record than ... the record length of an internal file.

The record length of your internal file being 10.

The usual caveats of relying on any particular behaviour hold.  I'd be disappointed, though, if something dramatic happened.

Comment: Be mindful that the definition status of the variable nominated by the iomsg specifier is not changed if the value of the variable set by the iostat specifier is zero.