# End of record when writing real to a string

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I am getting a runtime error using Fortran 95:

```
At line 73 of file calcCenterOfMass.f95
Fortran runtime error: End of record
```

Code in line 73 is

```
WRITE(TIMEDIR, '(f10.2)') CURRENTTIME
```

where `TIMEDIR` is a string and `CURRENTTIME` a real.

I guess the problem is that `TIMEDIR` has a length of four because the string has to be of the shape 0.00, 0.01 etc. But a default length real is longer than four characters.

Is that the problem, and then, how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, `timedir` has to be of length at least 10.  See, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29489388), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27462619) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32684816).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Format `f10.2` means 10 characters in length, with 2 decimals. (So it will be xxxxxxx.xx)

If you want 0.01 or so, you need format `f4.2`